# search error an unexpected network error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007003B)

Tags: enterprise-search

I need to search in file server , create new content source with address file://172.20.20.1/Software_Storage but crawl log search service has error

```
An unexpected network error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007003B)
```

Comment: Is it a share on a Windows Server 2012 or 2012 R2 Server?

Comment: May be related to [this questions and answer](https://serverfault.com/a/297859/423274)?. It reads: _" It turns out that the combination of having 802.1x configured (through GPO) and having [antivirus] configured to scan network drives when uploading large files to a DFS share"_.